# numpy matrix updating every second

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have a problem with Numpy matrix

I want to do this;
I am using "googlefinance" library to pull live stock price data, and from here, I want to make a matrix of the data I pull. For example,

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes

def live_price(symbol):
    price = getQuotes(symbol)[0].values()[3]
    return float(price)

live_price('a')
```

this will give me the current live price of stock 'a'

And I want to make a matrix like this;

```
A=np.matrix([live_price('a'),live_price('b'),live_price('c')])
```

This outputs:

```
matrix([[37.69, 9.04, 34.23]])
```

Here comes the problem. The problem is that when I run `A` like 10 seconds later, it should give me a matrix with updated price data since `live_price('symbol')` refreshes the data every time when google finance refreshes the price data.

If I only run `live_price('a')` every time what the price changes it will give me the changed new price. But when it is in the numpy matrix the prices are not updated it always gives me the same prices as the prices when I made the numpy matrix. How should I solve this problem. I want the numpy matrix `A` updates the price every time when I run `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ten seconds you should run:

```
A[0,0] = live_price('a')
```

to update the first element of the matrix.

For your mental health, 'explicit is better than implicit'.